# How "visualize" negative-dimensional space?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

The concept of negative-dimensional space was introduced in many  branches of geometry (topology, algebraic-geometry, derived-geometry, fractals, etc)
for example:

http://forthelukeofmath.com/documents/Wolcott-McTernan-workshop.pdf

Or

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative-dimensional_space

How "visualize" this? For example a (-2)-sphere

Comment: It is same as visualising -2 or 2, jus remember not to visualise 2 things, but number 2 only.

Comment: or just try substituting -2 for n sphere : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Comment: I can't access the first link and the second one does not exist.

Comment: [Here](http://www.archive.bridgesmathart.org/2012/bridges2012-637.pdf)'s an article about conceptualizing negative-dimensional space through performative art.

Comment: If we look at how the $\Sigma$ operation is defined in @Jair's link, it seems that a space with dimension $-n$ would have to be able to be combined with an $n$ dimensional space to form a zero dimensional space.

Answer (score 5):

A solid $-1$-ball is an *infinite periodic lattice*. For instance, the set of integers or the set of real roots of the sine function.

Let $h$ being the step of the lattice. Then

- The radius of the ball is $R=h/\pi$. Thus, unit ball is a lattice with step $\pi$ (such as the set of roots of the sine function).
- The volume of the ball is $V=\frac1{h}=\frac1{\pi R}$. It is the density of the lattice. A unit ball has volume $\frac 1\pi$.
- A single point is the limit case of a ball when the volume is zero.
- Any point of the ball can be its center. Thus a given lattice can represent different balls depending on what point we consider the center. It is possible that two balls intersect only at center.
- The ball is also a solid cube with side $h$. Thus a unit cube is a lattice with step $1$, its volume is $1$. Thus, in dimensions 0,1 and -1 a ball is also a cube.
- One can see that the lattice is a fractal of dimension $-1$: when scaled by $1/2$ (shrinked by factor 2) it contains 2 copies of original. $\frac{\ln{2}}{\ln 1/2}=-1$. For comparison, an interval (1-cube) if scaled by 2 contains 2 its original copies, so its dimension is 1, square (2-cube) if scaled by 2, contains 4 its copies, so its dimension is 2, cube if scaled by 2 contains 8 its copies, so its dimension is 3, point if scaled by 2 is still a point, so its dimension is 0, etc.

Comment: +1. The fractal interpretation has always resonated best with me.

Comment: nice ...................+1

Comment: This applies to all dimensions--that is, the lattice $V_n=\{\sum_1^n\alpha_k\vec{\omega_k}:(\alpha_k,\vec{\omega_k})\in\mathbb R\times \mathbb R^n, \vec{\omega_i}\neq k\vec{\omega_j}\forall k\}$ has dimension $-n$. However, your claim on volume is very sketchy to me. Lattices also don't follow many of the patterns integer dimensions do, however. For example, you can't compose a bunch of them to obtain a $0$D object the same way you can compose points to make a line.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad the formula for volume of a ball is ${\displaystyle V_{n}(R)={\frac {\pi ^{\frac {n}{2}}}{\Gamma \left({\frac {n}{2}}+1\right)}}R^{n},}$. Inserting $n=-1$ we get $V=\frac1{\pi R}$ and for $R=1$ we get the volume $1/\pi$. On the other hand, the volume of unit cube is always 1. I did not understand your formula or statement... Can you please clarify.

Comment: @Anixx For example, a lattice fulfills the requirement of negative dimension, but it doesn't fulfill any of the properties we expect negative dimensional objects to have. How can I have a vector of $-1$ elements? That is, how can I describe the space $\mathbb R^{-1}$?

Comment: @Annix $V_n$ is an arbitrary periodic lattice in dimension $n$.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad In the dimension $n<-1$ the lattice (like Gaussian integers) is a cube but I cannot tell what set would represent a ball.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad a question about metric is indeed open, I would like to see a metric on real line in which periodic lattices would be balls. We can build caninical algebra in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (including $n=0$, a zero ring), it would be interesting to see an algebra in $n=-1$.

Comment: @Anixx An initial guess at a "metric" (which is by no means a metric) might be $||x||:=\sin x$? Even better would be this funky thing: $||x||:=e^{2\pi ix}$.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad Unit cube is also a ball with radius 1/π. All points of a ball should have smaller distance from center than the radius.

Comment: @Annix $||x||=r\iff x=\arcsin r+2\pi k$. That was my reasoning. I didn't shift it so that it was $r$ units from $0$. Try $||x||=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}x$. It's not possible to get a consistent result with every $r$, given the metric chosen.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad my ideas were a) GCD/LCM-based b) That any point has two distances from zero, depending on "path": the normal one, which is "proper", and the biggest and secondary ones, which are divisors of the proper distance. c) The definition of a ball is based not on the distance from center but on the max distance between points.

Comment: How can an infinite lattice have finite area? There should be an explanation besides it just being $-1$d space

Comment: @TymaGaidash area? I do not know. The volume is density.

Comment: @Anixx Thanks for the correction; “volume” was meant instead of “area”. Why call the density of the lattice the volume? “Volume” is the amount of space an object takes up while density is the amount of something per volume. Right?

Comment: @TymaGaidash more dense lattice has more points, so its volume is greater, similar to how in dimension 1 longer interval has greater volume. According to the n-ball volume formula, volume of a ball is proportional to its radius raised to the power of the dimension. Volume of 3D-ball is proportional to the cube of the radius, area of a disk is proportional to the square to the radius, ets. In dimension -1, the volume is proportional to the inverse of the radius.

Comment: So I like the lattice example here because it even allows for a rich variety of spaces to be built up by considering lattices of irrational periods. There is also a Cartesian product of lattices. It’s unclear how to deal with the fact the 0-dimensional content of the lattice is infinity. You’d want to generalize the idea of measuring content somehow to get 0 here.

Comment: There’s an interesting shadow of an idea in the fact that the real line R (embeds into ambient R^1) quotiented by the lattice Z is S^1 (which embeds into ambient R^2) we get this relationship R^1/Z^(-1) = R^2. This goes further, quotienting a plane by a 2D lattice results in a torus that lives in 3D, but to draw the torus in a way so that every point on its surface truly looks the same, I *think* can only happen in R^4. This hints towards Alexander Conrad’s idea of the Cartesian quotient

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal if we take product of interval $[0,1)$ (which is 1-dimensional fractal) and $1$-periodic lattice (-1-dimensional fractal), we get the real line. And real line is a $0$-dimensional fractal (scaling does not change it)

Comment: No you don’t get the real line, you get a (1-1) dimensional object which is lattice of intervals with the intervals orthogonal to the axis of the lattice. This object still behaves 0-dimensionally at least in the sense of probability distributions. See my comment on Conrad’s answer. The problem with trying to say the line is 0 dimensional because scaling doesn’t change it, is that similar arguments claim each of  R^n is 0 dimensional, and there’s no need for this. Agreed we are all abusing notation and terminology here but some statements I’d argue are more catastrophic than others.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal I think we should define Cartesian product of 0-dimensional manifold just that: non-ortogonal intervals, layed consequently. And yes, fractal dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ is zero.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal look at it this way: -1-dimensional space can be represented as coil with thread on an infinitely long cylinder. The lattices are straight lines on this coil, crossing the thread periodically. Then Cartesian product of these lines with intervals of the thread perpendicular to them and having the same length as the interval of lattice would give the whole thread.

Comment: Cartesian products are always orthogonal and if we do the orthogonal product here and don’t identity this object as R^1 we still get our desired 0-dimensional behavior. Like suppose the measure of this space, (the sum of the length of all the line segments)  is S (we know it’s infinite but let’s give it a formal value S). If we cut the scale in half along the segment axis, the the total measure of the space is now S/2. If we scale in half across the lattice axis instead the length is 2S. It’s works beautifully, no need to identity this object with R^1.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal in coil analogy the cartesian product will be orthogonal and will give R^1.

Comment: I feel like the model you have invented here works so well without invoking this coil or identifying that collections of segments as equivalent to R_1 that it feels extremely wrong to now do so. Like it just works out of the box. Why do we want to now declare that R^1 is 0 dimensional.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal R^1 is 0-dimensional following the fractal dimension definition. As to the coil analogy, I find it very useful. I am now thinking about trigonometry of -1-dimensional space. A lattice is characterized by two numbers: phase (analoguous to angle) and density (analoguous to length). Thus, the set of oots of cosine and the set of roots of sine are orthogonal, because the phase shift between them is $\pi/2$... What is even more interesting is that in -2-dimension there are 3 parameters: phase, angle and density.

Comment: @Anixx which fractal dimension are you using? There are many but none that I know of assign the real line dimension 0.

Comment: Moving on from our R^1 scuffle, The phase stuff you are considering is cool and seems like the correct next idea to consider to me. It also seems that’s possible to model 0 dimensional space via a geometric spaced lattice, i conjecture that every real number r has a corresponding lattice subset of R^1 that exhibits r-dimensional behavior. Your notions of phase also generalize readily in this space even in the geometric case. There is some interplay between phase and scaling that the geometric case makes apparent.

Comment: *geometric meaning exponential. So like the lattice of all points $2^n$ where n is an integer. If you divide or multiply by 2 this remains unchanged. If you scale by any other real number that’s not an integer power of 2 there is a phase coupling that occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence of the Wikipedia article you link to ends with a pointer to the first reference of the article, which is a link to a pdf called [Imagining Negative-Dimensional Space](http://www.archive.bridgesmathart.org/2012/bridges2012-637.pdf). Might be a starting point.

But generally I'd say it's not always the best thing to just cling to words when contexts generalizes. In math, you may have some thing $f(x)$ where $x$ is a $X$, and then somebody sees you can keep the formal form of $f$ but use a $y$ of $X$ and still have $f(y)$ make some sense. If $x$ was called foo, it might not be worth trying to read foo-ness into $y$. It's tuning in on the web-stream of your favorite radio station and searching for the electromagnetic waves in the radio frequency range.

Comment: Old link is dead, see here: http://www.archive.bridgesmathart.org/2012/bridges2012-637.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Negative-dimensional space seems good, but in the contexts typically used, it does not make sense. However, I do cover the possibilities of there being negative dimensional objects.

---

For example, under certain conditions, I can say that $N$ algebraic equations in $M$ variables specifies an $M-N$ dimensional space. So, for example, the curves: $$x^2-2y^2+z^2=5,\\ x+y-z=1,$$ specify a $3-2=1$D space, that is, their intersection is some elliptical shape in 3D. As such, if I were to have the set of equations:
$$x^2-3xy+z^3=5z\\3x-3y+z^2=1\\x^2-y+z^5=0\\ x^2y^3-z^6x^7-x^7+y^3=0,$$ assuming such an intersection exists, the intersection is negative-dimensional, that is, we have $3$ variables and $4$ equations. However, this often simply means that the solution *doesn't exist*. If it does, it is never negative-dimensional.

Another example: I can have the vector $$(u^3-3uv-v^5,uv,u^2+v^2)\in\mathbb R^3$$ describe a set of points that make a $2$D surface. And in this context, the dimension of the surface corresponds to the number of input variables used. Yet I cannot have $-1$ variables.

---

Not *all* hope is lost. You can *define* $-1$ variables to mean **something**.
However, the reason we have negative numbers and square roots, etc., is because there was sufficient context in which to define them. Square roots were inventable since there was an implicit structure available to make their definition coherent ($x:=\sqrt{y}\iff x^2=y$). Similarly with negative numbers ($x:=-y\iff x+y=0$). You have to provide the larger context. Fractals seem to do a good job, and they have my vote.

---

Side notes: Consider that, typically, the volume of an $d$D array of points is on the order of $n^d$ for side length $n$. This gives the definition of dimension:

$$d:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln V(n\vec{s_0})-\ln V(\vec{s_0})}{\ln n}$$ for "initial vector sidelength" $\vec{s_0}$ of our object and volume $V(\vec{s})$ (as a function of side-lengths $\vec s$). For example, a rectangular prism with volume $V(x,y,z)=xyz$ has dimension $$d_{\text{Box}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n^3xyz-\ln xyz}{\ln n}=3.$$ So we're looking for some object that has a single parameter defining its volume such that the function we obtain for volume has $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln V(ns_0)-\ln V(s_0)}{\ln n}=-1.$$

Comment: If to think about it, I think, the following definition of metric on $\mathbb R^{-1}$ would work: each two points have a proper distance between them, equal to the usual distance. There is also infinite set of secondary distances, which are fractions (divisors) of the proper distance. Secondary distances are all smaller than proper distance. For instance, two points $0$ and $\pi$ have proper distance $\pi$ and secondary distances $\pi/2$, $\pi/3$, $\pi/4$, etc. Then a ball is a set of points, which have at least one distance from the center (proper or not) equal to radius, plus center itself.

Comment: Then, all the points of the ball except the center will be the shell, the center will be interrior. The two points whose proper distance to the center are equal to radius will be "proper shell".

Comment: @Anixx Hmm. Notice that $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^{-1}\simeq \mathbb R^{n-1}$. I think this is best addressed by inverting the notion of a cartesian product to a cartesian *division*.

Comment: @Anixx And so then, in that context, $\mathbb R^{-1}$ is defined as $\mathbb R\div\mathbb R^2$

Comment: What is cartesian division?

Comment: @Anixx I made it up. You'd have to invent it.

Comment: This might be smoke and mirrors but I think i see an interesting idea here. Consider R^1 x Z, a lattice of lines. Now suppose on each line there was a probability distribution. And suppose want want to look at the sum of the probability across all the distributions inside a circle of radius r. If we divide the lattice axis by 2 we would double the amount of lines passing through circle (doubling that measure roughly), but if the cut the R^1 axis by half, we would shrink all those functions (possibly cutting  our measure in half?) so this (1-1) dimensional space has the property that…

Comment: …dividing both axis by 1/2 leaves a measure on the space unchanged. Which is effectively 0 dimensional behavior.